# How to add S line in logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I was plotting the results of a logistic regression, but instead of the expected S curve, I got a line like this:

But I want it to be like this one:

Comment: The curve reflects your data. At the left side of the plot, you seem to have only about 40% "no doctor visited". You do not have data showing that "no doctor visited" is ever close to 0. It would probably be easier to compare the plots if you used `jitter()` to spread the points slightly above and below the 0 and 1 horizontal lines.

Comment: @dcarlson, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The curve reflects your data. At the left side of the plot, you seem to have only about 40% "no doctor visited". You do not have data showing that "no doctor visited" is ever close to 0. It would probably be easier to compare the plots if you used `jitter()` to spread the points slightly above and below the 0 and 1 horizontal lines. Here is an example using the `iris` data set:

```
data(iris)
oldp <- par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
```

The first example tries to predict if the species is setosa or virginica using the Sepal Length. These species are well separated.

```
iris.sub1 <- subset(iris, Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica"), select=c(Species, Sepal.Length))
iris.sub1 <- droplevels(iris.sub1)
iris.logist1 <- glm(Species~Sepal.Length, iris.sub1, family=binomial())
iris.sub1.pred1 <- predict(iris.logist1, data.frame(Sepal.Length=seq(4, 8, by=.1)), type="response")
boxplot(Sepal.Length~Species, iris.sub1)
plot(as.numeric(Species)-1~jitter(Sepal.Length, 2), iris.sub1, ylab="Probability virginica", xlab="Sepal Length")
lines(seq(4, 8, by=.1), iris.sub1.pred1)
```

The top row shows a boxplot for Sepal Length for the two species. Notice how well they are separated. Only the longest setosa sepals overlap with the smallest virginica ones. The logistic regression produces a classic S-shaped curve.

```
iris.sub2 <- subset(iris, Species %in% c("versicolor", "virginica"), select=c(Species, Sepal.Width))
iris.sub2 <- droplevels(iris.sub2)
iris.logist2 <- glm(Species~Sepal.Width, iris.sub2, family=binomial())
iris.sub2.pred2 <- predict(iris.logist2, data.frame(Sepal.Width=seq(2, 5, by=.1)), type="response")
boxplot(Sepal.Width~Species, iris.sub2)
plot(as.numeric(Species)-1~jitter(Sepal.Width, 2), iris.sub2, ylab="Probability virginica", xlab="Sepal Width")
lines(seq(2, 5, by=.1), iris.sub2.pred2)
```

The bottom row tries to predict if species is versicolor or virginica using  Sepal Width. Note the box plot indicates that these two species overlap substantially. The logistic regression produces a very shallow S-shaped curve. It appears that your data overlap even more than this.

[image: Comparison of two logistic regressions]